# Starting Stencil Locally on existing store creates error 310 too many redirects

Tags: bigcommerce

I am able to run stencil locally just fine on our other stores, but I am getting this error on one. Any ideas on how to fix

Comment: I am seeing this error as well. I have yet to figure out how to fix it. Running on Windows 10.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is that store configured to force load HTTPS?

Comment: No, for me the one that is not working it is not set to force HTTPS.